# How to get data from AJAX request with Symfony 4?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to get data from an AJAX request with Symfony 4 and what I get is not that I'm expecting.

Here is my routes.yaml

```
(...)
ajax_test:
    path: /ajax/test
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\AjaxTestController::test' }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

My controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AjaxTestController extends AbstractController
{
    public function test(Request $request) {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
            $response = $serializer->serialize('test ok', 'json');

            return new JsonResponse(['data' => $response]);
        }

        return new Response("test ko", 400);
    }
}
```

Here is the template where I make the AJAX request :

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}

{% set active = 'connexion' %}

{% block page_title 'Login' %}

{% block final_javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('sendCredentials') }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    (...)

            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form id="connexion-form" action="{{ path('security_connexion') }}" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="_email" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button">Se connecter</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

And finally the JavaScript file (`sendCredentials.js`) where I make AJAX request :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#connexion-form').submit(function(event) {
        sendCredentials($('#email').val(), $('#password').val());
    });
});

function sendCredentials(username, password) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/test",
        data: {username: username, password: password},
        async: false
    }).done(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg['data']);
        console.log(msg);
    });
}
```

The first log `console.log(msg['data']);` displays `undefined`. The second log `console.log(msg);` displays me the html code of the template itself, that is to say the code of the template generated by twig. I don't understand why. How to get the data wanted : `'test ok'` ?

P.S. : I don't use credentials yet (`username` and `password`), I'm just making tests, I want first the AJAX request to work.

Comment: If you get HTML in `console.log(msg);`, my best guess is you're getting `Response` instance, instead of `JsonResponse`. Can you `var_dump($request->isXmlHttpRequest())` ?

Comment: I think you don't need `action="{{ path('security_connexion') }}"` if you're submitting a form through AJAX.

Comment: I can't dump `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`, it seems that the code of controller is not executed and I get the HTTP 302 on `/ajax/test`

Comment: I think this happens because of the `action="{{ path('security_connexion') }}"` bit. Remove it and try again.

Comment: I get the same thing when removing it.

Comment: Try adding `event.preventDefault();` in your closure before you call `sendCredentials()`

Comment: I get the same thing. Why am I having HTTP 302 ?

Comment: No idea. Is your sever set up correctly? Do you have other routes that work?

Comment: I have corrected some access_control settings and now it works fine. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Happy coding. '